# Why form validation errors are not showing in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular, forms, validation

I have been working for a week in a project, recently I notice I don't get any form validation errors, and I don't know why.

I tried with this code, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

```html
<form>
 <div>
   <label for="choose">Would you prefer a banana or a cherry?</label>
   <input type="text" id="choose" name="i_like" required minlength="6" maxlength="6">
 </div>
 <div>
   <label for="number">How many would you like?</label>
   <input type="number" id="number" name="amount" value="1" min="1" max="10">
 </div>
 <div>
   <button>Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

I replace my entire `app.component.html` with the code and the validation message was not showing, then I replace `index.html` body and it works, I don't know what could be the problem in my project.

I also tried to remove boostrap and any dependency in my angular.json `scripts`, `styles` and `assets` from the project but still not showing.

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: I am using angular 11.1.4

Comment: I have shared my answer in detail please check it

Answer (score 0):

For angular above 2+ version you need to create reactive forms. Please refer below code for the same

**app.module.ts**

You need to import ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Now you can use reactive form in your app.component.ts

**app.component.ts**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   myForm: FormGroup;

   constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
   ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.myForm = this.fb.group({
         i_like: ['', Validators.required],
         amount: ['', Validators.required]
      });
   }

   onSubmit(): void{
   }
}
```

Now in your **app.component.html** you need to create form

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSumbit)="onSubmit()">
 <div>
   <label for="choose">Would you prefer a banana or a cherry?</label>
   <input type="text" id="choose" formControlName="i_like" required minl ength="6" maxlength="6">
   <p *ngIf="myForm.get('i_like').hasError('required')">Please select this field.</p>
 </div>
 <div>
   <label for="number">How many would you like?</label>
   <input type="number" id="number" formControlName="amount" value="1" min="1" max="10">
   <p *ngIf="myForm.get('amount').hasError('required')">Please select this field.</p>
 </div>
 <div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

You can also set the multiple types of validators in Reactive Forms. Please refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) link for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

validation works differently in angular as in normal js:

- you can do it in a reactive way: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms
- or template-driven way: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-template-driven-forms

Normally, the reactive way is preferred because it can be refactored more easily to a component later if the code base gets bigger